# The reference to the class in ES6 is lost

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, class-reference

I have the following structure Javacript es5-es6 and the controller class loses the reference in the class Get, I was already investigating but I can not find how to avoid losing the reference.

```
class Controller {
    constructor() {
        this.name = 'Test';
    }
    test() {
        console.log(1, this.name);
    }
}

referenceController = new Controller();
// working reference: console.log(1, 'Test');
referenceController.test();


class Get {
    method() {
        return {
            controller: referenceController.test
        }
    }
}

// Lost self reference: console.log(1, undefined)
new Get().method().controller()
```

Comment: `obj.test()` calls test as a **method**, with the syntax `context dot method`. Passing `obj.test` passes test as a reference to that **function,** without the context, and no longer as a method. You have to bind functions to the right context, because they don't know about `this`, or always call `obj.test`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this section, you add the test function as a property of the returned object.

```
{
    controller: referenceController.test
}
```

Then, when you call it as a method of that object (`method().controller()`) `this` refers to the object, and the `name` property is read from the object.

You could bind the context to preserve the reference:

```
referenceController.test.bind(referenceController)
```

Comment: now is working, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Your `method` function returns an object with key `controller` whose value is **not a reference to the instance of the `Controller` class** but a **function** that references **`this`**.

The `this` context of a method will be assigned to the object that it is attached to ***when it is invoked***.

So `new Get().method().controller()`

Calls the method `test` where `this` is the value that `new Get().method()` resolves to which is:

```
{
  controller: referenceController.test
}
```

Hence it logs out `undefined`

---

### **Amend your Get class as follows:**

```js
class Controller {
    constructor() {
        this.name = 'Test';
    }
    test() {
        console.log(1, this.name);
    }
}

referenceController = new Controller();
// working reference: console.log(1, 'Test');
referenceController.test();

class Get {
    method() {
        return {
            controller: referenceController
        }
    }
}

// this logs out correctly
new Get().method().controller.test();
```

The above works because `new Get().method().controller` resolves to the `Controller` class instance referenceController that **does** have a property defined `name` with a value.